# Excel Userform Iframe Autoscroll

Tags: excel, vba

What I have is a user form with an image a iframe with multiple input fields.  I have created a scrollable region as all the input fields do not fit on the userform.  What happens is when i click a certain part of the image the iframe will scroll downwards to the input box applicable an set foceu.  This works great using the script below, Now my question is how do i set it to go horizonatal instead of vertical now

```
Sub scrollFrame(topVisibleControl As Object)
' Declares sub named scrollFrame and (procedure scoped) variable named topVisibleControl
Frame10.ScrollLeft = ScrollTop = topVisibleControl.Top
End Sub
```

I call the function with

```
Call scrollFrame(ComboBoxga37)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trial An Error I figured out if anyone sels interested here is the script below

```
Sub scrollFrame(leftVisibleControl As Object)
' Declares sub named scrollFrame and (procedure scoped) variable named topVisibleControl
Frame10.ScrollLeft = leftVisibleControl.Left
End Sub
```